# EF6 and missing provider

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, entity, entity-framework-5

`enter code here`I write in VS2010 a .NET 4.0 Application and will use EF6. Here is my App.Config:

```
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" requirePermission="false" />
```

To change the connectionsinfo I use following code:

```
Public ReadOnly Property SqlConnectionString As String
    Get
        With sqlBuilder

            .DataSource = ServerName
            .InitialCatalog = DatabaseName

            If DatabaseUserName.Length = 0 Then
                .IntegratedSecurity = True
            Else
                .IntegratedSecurity = False
                .UserID = DatabaseUserName
                .Password = DatabasePassword
            End If

            sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = True

        End With

        Return sqlBuilder.ToString & ";App=EntityFramework"
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property EntityConnectionString As String
    Get
        Dim _metaData As String = ""

        With entityBuilder
            .Provider = ProviderName
            .ProviderConnectionString = SqlConnectionString

            _metaData = "res://" & DatabaseModelAssembly & "/" & DatabaseModelName & ".csdl|"
            _metaData = _metaData & "res://" & DatabaseModelAssembly & "/" & DatabaseModelName & ".ssdl|"
            _metaData = _metaData & "res://" & DatabaseModelAssembly & "/" & DatabaseModelName & ".msl"

            .Metadata = _metaData
        End With

        Return entityBuilder.ToString

    End Get
End Property

Public Function ConnectionTest() As Boolean
    Try

        Dim conn As New EntityConnection(EntityConnectionString)
        conn.Open()
        Console.WriteLine("Just testing the connection.")
        conn.Close()

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return False

    End Try

End Function
```

If i try to check the connection with "open" following error come up:

```
Data.SqlClient' ADO.NET provider. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file
```

The Assemblies EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer are in the same folder as the DAL-Class and the EntityFramework.SqlServer is build with the EntityFramework.dll

Did someone can help me?